# I can not align the title of a action bar ,So that it is in the middle

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

[image] I try to make the text written inside action bar in the middle
,I use the toolbar.xml through  Call the function 
 Which is Inside the  xml file 
I tried many times to find solutions ,But without any result
I have used many functions  Such as the function setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
and setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) with setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL), I have also tried Through some xml codes By the gravity property .

```
    See the Java code :

       private void initToolbar(){
            Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            TextView mToolBarTextView = (TextView) 
            findViewById(R.id.text_view_toolbar_title);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            }
            // mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.btn_back);
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
             mToolBarTextView.setText(R.string.title_mc);
            mToolBarTextView.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.TextBarStyle);
              //  mToolBarTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
             // mToolBarTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            // mToolBarTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            // mToolBarTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            //   mToolBarTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        }


    // See the my style : 
      <style name="TextBarStyle" parent="TextView.DefaultStyle">
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        </style>


    // Look at the toolbar xml : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tool_bar_text_size"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    // here is activity xml : 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".about_us.AboutUs">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/about_us2"
                android:textSize="19sp"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#000"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_us4"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_us5"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_us6"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#000"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does adding this `<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>` in your style work??

Comment: Does adding this `<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>` in your style work??

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: mToolBarTextView.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.TextBarStyle); what is the R.style.TextBarStyle ?

Comment: See the top code :    <style name="TextBarStyle" parent="TextView.DefaultStyle">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>

Comment: What is your app theme? Are u using AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: calss activity is  extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: I posted an answer please try and let me know. @ahmed

Comment: i have tried but not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a kind of hack. But will work.  Toolbar won't provide any method to align title exactly at the center of the toolbar when the Navigation button is present. As per the document, we can use "Insets" see the code below.

```
 mToolBarTextView.setPadding(-mToolbar.getContentInsetStartWithNavigation(),0,0,0);
```

Please **dont use any style** , please **remove** this line from your code and try

```
 mToolBarTextView.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.TextBarStyle);
```

As per the documentation 
 Insets define the minimum margin for these components
     * and can be used to effectively align Toolbar content along well-known gridlines.

You may have to change padding left or right depends on RTL true or false. May be.
Please try and let me know.

Comment: @ahmed I updated the answer , you should remove mToolBarTextView.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.TextBarStyle); line from the code as well. I checked on device and its working. let me know.

Comment: Does not work with   android:supportsRtl="true" I need to work in case true , Works only with  android:supportsRtl="false"  How to make it Works with functionality android:supportsRtl="true" ??

Comment: Thanks for u , it's works now     if(config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
  mToolBarTextView.setPadding(+mToolbar.getContentInsetStartWithNavigation(),0,0,0);
        }else{
            mToolBarTextView.setPadding(-mToolbar.getContentInsetStartWithNavigation(),0,0,0);
        }

Comment: mToolBarTextView.setPadding(mToolbar.getContentInsetStartWithNavigation(),0,0,0); for RTL

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.avezraj.testanimation.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test1" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

simply use relative layout for this